# Inserting interpolated "in-between" frames to a frame animation in Flash

Tags: animation, adobe-flash

I've just started learning multiplication animations and I'm trying to draw some torch. I've drawn the fire animation and I'm sorta fine with it, it is made of fills I've drawn with brush tool and then bucket`ed. But for an unrelated reason I want to double the framerate without increasing the speed and that would double all the frames. I was thinking, is there a way to not double the existing frames but auto-create in-between frames? I think Flash should be capable of transitioning one fill to another, maybe there's a way to get the frame that is in the middle between the two? I tried googling that but I'm not really sure how to phrase that question and all I'm getting is Tweening suggestion to make frame transition smoother, but I would like to export it to PNGs later so I would need the actual frame.

Hope somebody here could help me with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `shape tween` to transform the frames by adding interpolated results in between. Read this help page on [shape tweening](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WS58E1E1A4-9296-4b75-AB74-D9D545892556.html). However, this only really works out in cases where you *planned*  to do the tween beforehand*. You can try a blind shape tween but the results are going to be hit or miss. There is no guarantee that it will work out well.

To do a shape tween just select your frames and right click and choose create motion tween. Most likely you will also need to make a few shape hints as well. Before doing this for the first time try this out on something simple. Otherwise you will just be overwhelmed by trying to simultaneously understand several issues.

Tweens do produce actual frames if you have frames between.

[image]

**Image 1**: Example of 2 frames and a few tween frames between the keys.

* Animation is best approached by incremental testing and thorough planning. Otherwise you end up redoing a lot of work and wasting time that could have been avoided by planning. Never expect to be able to solve problems as they arise. Planning takes far less time than fixing errors.

Comment: Thanks for a good reply, looks like it would be easier to draw the in-between shapes by hand using onion skin :)

Comment: @pokrishka Often it is so. If you would have planned for tweening then it would probably work out pretty well. There is no magic that you didn't create. Oh and **PS**: often it is a good idea to hold off your acceptance to solicit more answers.